# How to call a javascript function in php code

Tags: javascript, php

i got a question about how to calling a javascript function in php script with if else statement

here is my php code

```
if (!$output) {

    !! here i want to call a javascript function !!



// $status = "Server has been shutdown!";
// $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $serverDate = time();
 $serverStatus = 0;



} else {
```

here is the javascript i want to call i just want to let you guys know that i added the **function OfflineStatus(){};** idk if that works to call the VAR variabel?

```
  function OfflineStatus() {
     var nodes = [
      { hostname: "", status: "OFFLINE", address: "", icon: "tasks" },
      { hostname: "", status: "OFFLINE", address: "", icon: "tasks" }
    ];
    }
```

the orginal code is this

```
 var nodes = [
      { hostname: ", status: "OFFLINE", address: "", icon: "tasks" },
      { hostname: "", status: "OFFLINE", address: "", icon: "tasks" }
    ];
```

Comment: You can't call a JavaScript function from PHP, because the PHP executes on the web server and JavaScript executes in the browser. Also, the `OfflinStatus()` function that you show has no effect, because it creates a *local* variable that is never used.

Comment: php knows nothing about JavaScript and JavaScript knows nothing about php.

Comment: Please explain the big picture. What do you want to acomplish? Ussually you will want to load your php+html and in any case run some javascript when the page has finished loading.

Comment: Well, that's great learning something new everyday...

Comment: Use Jquery/Ajax for this type of work...

Comment: What i'm doing here is a status script, when the server is offline i just want to load this bit of code from javascript if else statement in php to see if server online or not then load in javascript function

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to generate javascript string inside `<script></script>`

```
<script>
<?php
  if (!$output) {
    echo "OfflineStatus();";
  }
?>
</script>
```